# How can I replace below string with X using regex?

Tags: java, regex

**Input :** KEV32KUNAPP003-10.210.17.43-8050-ABCTMD1

**Expected Result :** XXX32KUNAPP003-XX.XXX.17.43-8050-ABCTMD1

**Description :** KEV is static string needs to be replaced with X.
And Middle part of string contains IP address (IPv4) 
And first two nodes of IP Address needs to be replace with X.

I am using java. I want to replace above string using regex.

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result? How did it differ from the intended result? SO is not here to write code for you. Also please don't just attach every regex tag to your question when it's just a general regex question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to mark same amount of `X`s for IP, but if putting `XXX` for each segment is acceptable, the following is the best match I can do:

Find:

```
(^KEV)(.+-)([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(-.+$)
```

Replace with:

```
XXX$2XXX.XXX.$5.$6$7
```

Test: http://regexr.com/3g03j